# How can i push an array into another array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to create an array like below.

```js
var path = [
  [41.02178, 29.26108],
  [41.02196, 29.26067],
  [41.02251, 29.26031],
  [41.02258, 29.26015],
  [41.02267, 29.25926]
];
```

In my code I tried this:

```js
var loc =[];
for (var i = 0; i < result.ResponseData.length; i++) 
{
   loc = [result.ResponseData[i].Latitude, result.ResponseData[i].Longitude];
   path.push(loc);
}
```

but this is the result:

```js
path=[0,0,29.26108,41.02178,29.26067,41.02196,29.26031,41.02251];
```

Comment: your data does not match the for loop.

Comment: how do you print path?

Comment: Your code should work from the incomplete exampled you provided. FWIW, you can do this too: `var path = result.ResponseData.map(function(item) { return [item.Latitude, item.Longitude] })`

Comment: Print `console.log(JSON.stringify(path));` and tell us what you see.

Comment: i want to use a path for a route in map. map wants an array which contains latitude and longitude. like i wrote in top of post named path.

Comment: im useing .net mvc, and "result.ResponseData" is a list of  public class MapViewModel
    {
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; } 

    }

Comment: @MürselYıldırım code shown won't produce the results you show. There is something missing. Assuming this is an ajax call show all relevant code

Answer (score -2):

Your code is correct, I think is the way you print path.

Path contains array of arrays as you want and you find it out with `console.log(path)`, with which you obtain:

```
Array [ Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2] ]
```

```js
var path = [
                  [41.02178, 29.26108],
                  [41.02196, 29.26067],
                  [41.02251, 29.26031],
                  [41.02258, 29.26015],
                  [41.02267, 29.25926]
                ];


var loc = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
      {
         loc = [1, 1];
         path.push(loc);
      }

console.log(path);

console.log("[[" + path.join("],\n[") + "]]");
```